# Mobile development with Rails using Wi-Fi network - Configuring url's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, routes, localhost

It's common when developing a web application to want to test it on mobile devices to ensure touch fallbacks and responsiveness.

As it happens, it's easy to do this over a Wi-Fi network. You just join the network on both *your computer running the localhost* and *the mobile device you want to access it on* and then enter the url on your mobile device:

```
http://<YOUR_COMPUTERS_IP>:3000
```

replacing `<YOUR_COMPUTERS_IP>` with your computer's ip address and `3000` with the port you are using.

This worked for basic routing.

The site i'm now working on however uses dynamic subdomains (users get their own subdomain) so is there any way to configure this to work with any subdomain?, so that you would be able to access

```
http://<SUBDOMAIN>.<YOUR_COMPUTERS_IP>:3000
```

on both your mobile and computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a subdomain onto an IP address directly, but there is a service called [xip.io](http://xip.io/) that was built to do just this.

```
http://<SUBDOMAIN>.<YOUR_COMPUTERS_IP>.xip.io:3000
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need!! But it doesn't work though

Comment: What kind of config did you need to do? It would be helpful to post it here for anyone that finds this later via Google.

Comment: We had some internal domain logic that we'd manually implemented.. It clashed with the xip.io .. so we just had to sort that out. It wouldn't be a problem in most cases